# When a thread is blocked on Monitor.Enter(obj), is it put in obj's ready queue?

Tags: .net, multithreading, clr

If so, that would imply that the blocked thread can enter when another thread calls `Monitor.Wait(obj)`. This seems a little odd to me in that it must contend with other threads in the ready queue.

If not, can it only un-block when `Monitor.Exit(obj)` is called? Or is it in obj's waiting queue?

This isn't clearly documented in the MSDN Library class documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the blocked thread can enter when another thread calls `Monitor.Wait`. Why would it not be able to?

In particular, it *has* to be able to - as the thread which is currently blocking may be the one which is going to call `Pulse`.

Consider a producer/consumer queue:

```
Producer                Consumer

                        Enter lock
Enter lock (block)
                        Check: queue is empty
                        Wait (block)
Unblocked
Add item to queue
Pulse
Exit lock
                        Unblocked (enters lock again)
                        Check: queue is now not empty
                        Fetch item
                        Exit lock
```

This scenario wouldn't work if the producer thread were still waiting for an Exit call.

Comment: I see, the example basically proves that if you're even gonna support Wait/Pulse, then blocking on Enter requires going to ready since Wait/Pulse can only be called between calls to Enter and Exit. But, since threading is complex enough and I don't have access to the source, I also expect the documentation to explicitly explain Enter in terms of the queues. Thank you for confirming and explaining.